# export my output to a text file (python3) line 15 and 30

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, sys

I want to export the output to this code into a text file. i tried to do this several different ways. sometimes i would have no errors but when i go to open the text file it is blank. i want to save the print commands to a text file. what is the best way for python 3?

```
import tkinter
import datetime
import tkinter as tk

window_main = tk.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart', )
window_main.geometry("400x200")

entry_1 = tk.StringVar()

entry_widget_1 = tk.Entry(window_main, textvariable=entry_1)
entry_widget_1.pack()


def submitValues():
print(entry_1.get())


submit = tk.Button(window_main, text="Submit", command=submitValues)
submit.pack()

window_main.mainloop()

window_main = tkinter.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart', )
window_main.geometry("400x200")
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()


def submitFunction():

  print(date_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M"))


button_submit = tkinter.Button(window_main, text="Clock In", command=submitFunction)
button_submit.config(width=40, height=5)


button_submit.pack()
window_main.mainloop()

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: first you have to put code with correct indentations - at this moment your code has wrong indentations and we can't test it.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't show line numbers so we don't know which line is 15 and 30

Comment: print(entry_1.get())

Comment: better show code in which you try to write in file.

Comment: print(date_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M"))

Comment: if you want to write in file then you have `open()`, `write()`, `close()`. If you will open many times then you may need to use `append mode` to keep previous content. OR open file at start and close at the end.

Comment: show these lines in question - more people will see it and more people may help you.

Comment: hello i just want the print command to be exported out of python to a text file(notepad)

Comment: you can send text to file on disk, not to file already opened in notepad. You will have to open this file manually - or use `os.system("notepad textfile.txt")`

Comment: furas, can you type out quick example if you dont mind? so if i open notepad and do a save as "test.txt" on my desktop can i write my output to that file?

Comment: i don't understand why you want to use `save` - Python saves text directly to file on disk and you don't need to use `notepad` and `save` for this

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is your problem. And I don't understand why you want to use `notepad` and `save` for this.

Python has `open()`, `write()` and `close()` to write text directly to file.

```
# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for funcitons

def submit_values():
    text = entry_1.get()

    print(text)

    fh = open('test.txt', 'a')
    fh.write(text + "\n")
    fh.close()
    
def submit_function():
    text = date_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M") 

    print(text)

    fh = open('test.txt', 'a')
    fh.write(text + "\n")
    fh.close()
```

or using `with`

```
# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for funcitons

def submit_values():
    text = entry_1.get()

    print(text)

    with open('test.txt', 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(text + "\n")
    
def submit_function():
    text = date_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M") 

    print(text)

    with open('test.txt', 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(text + "\n")
```

Because you want to write in many functions so it has to open it in `append mode` to append new text to previous text. Using `write mode` it would remove previous content.

---

Eventually you can use it with `print(..., file=...)` to send `print()` to file and then you don't have to add new line `\n`

```
def submit_values():
    text = entry_1.get()

    with open('test.txt', 'a') as fh:
        print(text, file=fh)
     
def submit_function():
    text = date_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M") 

    with open('test.txt', 'a') as fh:
        print(text, file=fh)
```

---

Full working code

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for funcitons

def submit_values():
    text = entry_1.get()

    print(text)

    fh = open('test.txt', 'a')
    fh.write(text + "\n")
    fh.close()

    window_main.destroy()  # close window
     
def submit_function():
    text = date_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M") 

    print(text)

    fh = open('test.txt', 'a')
    fh.write(text + "\n")
    fh.close()

    window_main.destroy()  # close window

# --- main ---

# - window 1 -

window_main = tk.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart', )
window_main.geometry("400x200")

entry_1 = tk.StringVar()

entry_widget_1 = tk.Entry(window_main, textvariable=entry_1)
entry_widget_1.pack()

submit = tk.Button(window_main, text="Submit", command=submit_values)
submit.pack()

window_main.mainloop()

# - window 2 -

window_main = tk.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart')
window_main.geometry("400x200")
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()

button_submit = tk.Button(window_main, text="Clock In", command=submit_function)
button_submit.config(width=40, height=5)

button_submit.pack()
window_main.mainloop()

# - end -

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

You can also assign file to  `sys.stdout` to send all `print()` to file

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('test.txt', 'a')

# ... code ...

sys.stdout = old_stdout   # assign back to display `input()` in console
```

Full working code

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
import sys

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for funcitons

def submit_values():
    text = entry_1.get()

    print(text)

    window_main.destroy()  # close window
     
def submit_function():
    text = date_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M") 

    print(text)

    window_main.destroy()  # close window

# --- main ---

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('test.txt', 'a')

# - window 1 -

window_main = tk.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart', )
window_main.geometry("400x200")

entry_1 = tk.StringVar()

entry_widget_1 = tk.Entry(window_main, textvariable=entry_1)
entry_widget_1.pack()

submit = tk.Button(window_main, text="Submit", command=submit_values)
submit.pack()

window_main.mainloop()

# - window 2 -

window_main = tk.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart')
window_main.geometry("400x200")
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()

button_submit = tk.Button(window_main, text="Clock In", command=submit_function)
button_submit.config(width=40, height=5)

button_submit.pack()
window_main.mainloop()

# - end -

sys.stdout = old_stdout   # assign back to display `input()` in console

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: furas, thank you, so my problem is i cant see the output into "test.txt" file on my desktop. when i open the file its blank...

Comment: maybe you save in file in one folder and you open file in different folder - maybe use full path `open("/full/path/to/file/on/desktop/test.txt", "a")`

Comment: "C:\Users\alijh\Desktop\test.txt"   --- so this is the file path i should type it in like this?

Comment: yes. But remeber that \ has special meaning in string - ie. `\t` means `tab`, `\Uxxx` means Unicode char with code `xxx` - so use double \\ in path `open("C:\\Users\\alijh\\Desktop\\test.txt", "a")` or use prefix `r` for `raw string` - `open(r"C:\Users\alijh\Desktop\test.txt", "a")`

Comment: Furas this worked!!!!

Comment: if you want to work with more files in the same folder then you can use `os.chdir("C:\\Users\\alijh\\Desktop")` to `CHange DIRectory` and later you can use `open("test.txt")`. You can also display `print( os.getcwd() )` to see `Current Working Directory`

Comment: my end goal is to export to excel file, but i wanted to learn text file first because if im not mistaking exporting to excel file is more tricky....